# Spit a column into multiple columns in bash

Tags: bash, awk

I am working on VM Linux Ubuntu and my goal is to form this input

```
4,4
3,8
4,2
4,8
6,8
5,1
4,5
6,9
4,2
5,4
5,9
5,9
7,2
4,9
4,4
5,1
```

to this output

```
4,4 6,8 4,2 7,2
3,8 5,1 5,4 4,9
4,2 4,5 5,9 4,4
4,8 6,9 5,9 5,1
```

And copy these values to an Excel file on Windows.

I wrote this command

```
cat text.txt |cut -f3| awk '1 ; NR%4==0 {printf"\n"} '|pr  -4 -t|column -t| tr -s '[:blank:]' '\t'
```

which works fine!

I counted the blanked lines to create each column as below :
`cat text.txt |cut -f3| awk '1 ; NR%4==0 {printf"\n"} '| awk '!NF {sum += 1} END {print sum}'`  --> I got 4 blanked lines, so I am adding 4 to this command `|pr -4 -t|`

My issue was when I had a larger file, let's say 160 lines (40 blanked lines).
Initially, the modification on this part `|pr -40 -t`  gave an error of `pr: page width too narrow`
so I changed to

```
 cat text.txt |cut -f3| awk '1 ; NR%4==0 {printf"\n"} '| pr -W200 -40 -t | column -t| tr -s '[:blank:]' '\t'
```

which seems to work; however, the copy and paste merges 4 values in the 26th column, like

```
  4,83,6     
  5,66,2     
  6,57,6     
  8,18,1
```

instead of

```
  4,8  3,6   
  5,6  6,2   
  6,5  7,6   
  8,1  8,1
```

Even though I tried different values on the `W` option, I assume that -W200 is responsible for this issue.
I have two questions.

1. Can a good proportion between the wide and blanked cells be found to fix this merging issue?
2. As my goal is to “paste” 4 lines next to each other, could someone help me to paste the values directly instead of counting the number of blanked lines first and then modifying the wide range as I did?

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: will the number of input lines always be a multiple of 4?

Comment: fwiw, I duplicated the sample 16-line input until I had  a 240-line input, ran it through you 2nd script, and did not see any issues with the 26th column (or any column for that matter); now, if I run `unix2dos text.txt` and run the 2nd script I only get 2 columns of output, but no merged columns like you show; at this point I'm unable to reproduce the 'merged' output you're showing for the 2nd script's output

Comment: @markp-fuso a) Mostly multiple of 3 and 4.  b)You gave me a good idea. Initially I used the copy and paste directly from the command line. I saved the file first, and I copied the values from the generated txt file and it seems fine!!!

Comment: if you still have the problematic data file you could try running it through `od` (eg, `od -c text.txt`) and look for any characters that are not in the group `1-9,\n<space>`

Comment: It's not clear if you want to get 4 columns or 4 rows or the same number of columns as rows determined by the square root of the number of input lines. Please [edit] your question to state which it is you want.

Comment: @EdMorton It is optional to be divided by 4. My point was to use a command and automatically divide/split a column into columns by a desired number. The issue with my command is that each time, I have to specify the wide range of the Excel separation. The first solution, provided by markp-fuso makes it automatic. Just declare the split number and you are done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of trying to reverse-engineer and understand OP's current code, and since OP is already using `awk`, I'd like to propose a single `awk` script to replace all of OP's current code:

```
awk -v n=4 '                   # set awk variable "n" to the number of output lines
BEGIN { OFS="\t" }
      { sub(/\r$/,"")          # strip out a trailing dos/windows line ending "\r"
        ndx = NR%n
        lines[ndx] = lines[ndx] (NR <= n ? "" : OFS) $1
      }
END   { for (i=1; i<=n; i++) {
            print lines[i%n]
        }
      }
' text.txt
```

**NOTE:** you can remove the `sub(/\r$/,"")` if you know for a fact the input file will never contain dos/windows line endings (`\r`); if the file does not include `\r` line endings then the `sub(/\r$/,"")` becomes a no-op that does nothing (other than use up a few cpu cycles)

For 4 lines (`n=4`) of output:

```
4,4     6,8     4,2     7,2
3,8     5,1     5,4     4,9
4,2     4,5     5,9     4,4
4,8     6,9     5,9     5,1
```

For 3 lines (`n=3`) of output:

```
4,4     4,8     4,5     5,4     7,2     5,1
3,8     6,8     6,9     5,9     4,9
4,2     5,1     4,2     5,9     4,4
```

For 7 lines (`n=7`) of output:

```
4,4     6,9     4,4
3,8     4,2     5,1
4,2     5,4
4,8     5,9
6,8     5,9
5,1     7,2
4,5     4,9
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the pieces of advice and the code. File manipulation, based on the little experience that I have, can indeed be PITA :P. I also tested your code for multiple splits...like instead of 4 lines for 16, 20 lines, and it works perfectly!!

Comment: This is the only `awk` here that correctly handles the case of number of input lines not being an even multiple of the number of columns. Well done!

Answer (score 2):

Another simple approach is to buffer the elements in an array using string concatenation in `awk`. No other process is needed, e.g.

```bash
awk '{n++; a[n] = (FNR > 4) ? a[n] " " $0 : $0; if (n == 4) n = 0 } END {for (i=1; i<=4; i++) print a[i] }' file
```

Essentially you build a 4-element array with each element being one of the final rows you want in your output. You concatenate every 4<sup>th</sup> value to each array element `1, 2, 3` and `4` in order, adding a space before each value after the first in each element.

After having read and concatenated all values into your array, you simply loop over the array elements in the `END` rule outputting each.

In an easier to read expanded form that would be:

```bash
awk '{
  n++
  a[n] = (FNR > 4) ? a[n] " " $0 : $0
  if (n == 4)
    n = 0
}
END {
  for (i=1; i<=4; i++)
     print a[i]
}' file
```

(adjust for whitespace as needed)

**Example Use/Output**

Using a heredoc to feed your example to `awk` you can do:

```
$ awk '{n++; a[n] = (FNR > 4) ? a[n] " " $0 : $0; if (n == 4) n = 0 } END {for (i=1; i<=4; i++) print a[i] }' << eof
4,4
3,8
4,2
4,8
6,8
5,1
4,5
6,9
4,2
5,4
5,9
5,9
7,2
4,9
4,4
5,1
eof

4,4 6,8 4,2 7,2
3,8 5,1 5,4 4,9
4,2 4,5 5,9 4,4
4,8 6,9 5,9 5,1
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you very much for the answer. I “played” with the command values of for (i=1; I <=4; i++), so Excel's "wide” works pretty well—just a comment on your command. If I copy and paste the values into Excel, all values go to the first cell. So, I have to add this command after your command.  |column -t| tr -s '[:blank:]' '\t'.

Comment: Yes, not knowing how Excel behaves and whether it would accept a space instead of a tab as the OFS, I just dropped the note to adjust whitespace as necessary. Glad you got it working. Good luck with your scripting!

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk:

```
awk '
{x++} # Increment x by 1
{if (x<=4) # Ensures a 5th line (or more) isn't added to output
        {col[x]=col[x] " " $1} # Concat 'x,x' value to appropriate array var
        else {x=1;col[x]=col[x] " " $1 }} # Necessary to prevent every 5th line from being skipped
        END { for (i=1;i<=4;i++)
                 {print col[i]}}
' $input_file
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Just a small detail. To copy and paste the values to excel, I added  $input_file | column -t| tr -s '[:blank:]' '\t'.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a Ruby to do that:

```
ruby -e 'inp=$<.read.split(/\R/) # The /\R/ is unerversual DOS or Unix
puts inp.each_slice(4).to_a.transpose.map{|e| e.join("\t")}' file
```

Prints:

```
4,4 6,8 4,2 7,2
3,8 5,1 5,4 4,9
4,2 4,5 5,9 4,4
4,8 6,9 5,9 5,1
```

If the line count length of your input is potentially not a perfect mutiple of the number of desired columns (ie, if your input is 15 lines or 17 lines rather that 16 lines which is an even multiple of 4) then you can do something like this:

```
ruby -e '
inp=$<.read.split(/\R/)

cols=4

inp=inp.each_slice(inp.length/cols+(inp.length % cols == 0 ? 0 : 1)).to_a
inp[0].zip(*inp[1..]){|sa| puts sa.join("\t")}
' <(seq 14)
```

Prints:

```
1   5   9   13
2   6   10  14
3   7   11  
4   8   12
```

That is the same behavior as `pr`.

Comment: Wooow that's crazy!!! Thanks a lot. I was not aware of Ruby, and I was surprised. Also, your command join the columns with tab delimiter which allows the direct paste in Excel!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to [GNU datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/), here is yet another solution. I added a few numbers to your example to show what happens with an item total not divisible by 4.

```
$ paste -d ' ' - - - - < file | datamash transpose -t ' '
4,4 6,8 4,2 7,2 2,3 2,7
3,8 5,1 5,4 4,9 2,4 2,8
4,2 4,5 5,9 4,4 2,5 
4,8 6,9 5,9 5,1 2,6
```

The **paste** command puts 4 items at a time from your list into a single line with items separated by a single space. **GNU datamash** then transposes the resulting table and separates the items with a single space.

Please note that this answer gives you a space-separated table. If you want a tab-separated table, the code is simpler:

```
paste - - - - < file | datamash transpose
```

Also, if you would like to make the length of the columns 7 (for example) instead of 4, you can do

```
$ paste $(printf '\x2d %.0s' {1..7}) < file | datamash transpose
4,4 6,9 4,4 2,8
3,8 4,2 5,1 
4,2 5,4 2,3 
4,8 5,9 2,4 
6,8 5,9 2,5 
5,1 7,2 2,6 
4,5 4,9 2,7
```

(tab-separated, but not obvious in this Stack Overflow display)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the command. I have another question. For some columns, you can add the respective number of "-".  If I want to add 400 columns, is it any way to do so? I assume I cannot add 400 times "-" ?

Comment: @KGee, the " - - - - " is what cuts the list of items into lots of 4 items, it doesn't affect the number of columns directly. I'll edit my answer to show one way to change the number of items grabbed at a time from the list and put into columns.

Answer (score 1):

Bash approach for example, read these values as an array:

```
arr=(
    4,4 #0
    3,8 #1
    4,2 #2
    4,8 #3

    6,8 #4
    5,1 #5
    4,5 #6
    6,9 #7

    4,2 #8
    5,4 #9
    5,9 #10
    5,9 #11

    7,2 #12
    4,9 #13
    4,4 #14
    5,1 #15
)
```

and process like this:

```
n=4

for((i=0; i<n; i++));{
    for((j=i; j<${#arr[@]}; j+=n));{
        printf "${arr[j]} "
    }
    echo
}
```

output:

```
4,4 6,8 4,2 7,2 
3,8 5,1 5,4 4,9 
4,2 4,5 5,9 4,4 
4,8 6,9 5,9 5,1
```

Hardcoded variant:

```
for((a=0,b=4,c=8,d=12; a<${#arr[@]}/4; a++,b++,c++,d++));{
    echo ${arr[a]} ${arr[b]} ${arr[c]} ${arr[d]}
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. The way you provide the command will be ideal for learning how to use arrays. I will definitely apply them in my next scripts.